# Execution time - SSIS

Tags: sql, ssis

i'm running a SSIS Package from Programmer Task with 15 Sql task inside that generate Data from a production enviroment... sometimes the execution time in Package doesn't end... so, i'm wondering if i lost connection, time execution is around 2 hours... if i run 8 SQL task and then the others, work without problem, but if i run everyone (SEQ), doesn't end.

I hope read some comment to help me fix that problem.

Thank You.

Ivan.

Comment: Try running Adam Machanic's sp_whoisactive while the package is running. This will give you some insight as to what is going on. Maybe your running into some blocking issues. http://sqlblog.com/blogs/adam_machanic/archive/2016/10/18/sp-whoisactive-the-big-fixes.aspx

Comment: can you elaborate your question? It will help us to understand it better. provide some snapshot of your package. What is a Programmer Task? Googled it but couldn't find anything related.